# What are the known convex polyhedra with congruent faces?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polyhedra, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

A monohedral polyhedron is one whose faces are all congruent. Note that this is a weaker condition than being isohedral (face-transitive).

We have a classification of all convex isohedral polyhedra, consisting of 30 classes of assorted finite polyhedra and infinite families. See [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html) for a list.

In the process of writing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886678/), I was trying to find instances of convex polyhedra which are monohedral but not isohedral, and struggled to find a classification of such shapes or even a list of known instances with an outline of which cases remain open.

The instances I know of beyond the isohedral polyhedra given above:

- When the faces are regular polygons, we can search among the Johnson solids to find three non-isohedral examples: the [snub disphenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid), the [triaugmented triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triaugmented_triangular_prism), and the [gyroelongated square bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_square_bipyramid).
- The [pseudo-deltoidal icositetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-deltoidal_icositetrahedron), the dual of the pseudorhombicuboctahedron. In footnote 46 on page 185 of *Advances in Discrete and Computational Geometry: Proceedings of the 1996 AMS-IMS-SIAM Joint Summer Research Conference, Discrete and Computational Geometry*, it is remarked that no other convex non-isohedral monohedra are known with non-triangular faces (or at least, none were known in 1996). ([Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=vtkaCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22monohedral%20polyhedra%22&source=bl&ots=g3uRanPNX-&sig=ACfU3U14093Sr_0qjAm10U4n9lXqc55HbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBuL_77d3sAhVeFTQIHTLqDosQ6AEwCHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22monohedral%20polyhedra%22&f=false) is a Google Books link to the relevant section of the previous source.)
- However, in a result apparently unknown to the above source, Ed Pegg provides what seems to be a counterexample in [this mathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667881/polyhedra-with-identical-faces); manually cutting out and folding the net, it does indeed seem to fold into a convex polyhedron.
- In the article [*The Bilinski Dodecahedron and Assorted Parallelohedra, Zonohedra, Monohedra, Isozonohedra, and Otherhedra*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00283-010-9138-7) (Grünbaum, B., 2010), the author includes the [rhombic icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_icosahedron) and the [Belinski dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinski_dodecahedron), and cites Belinski as proving that these are the only convex monohedra with centrally symmetric faces (such polyhedra termed *isozonohedra*) not already listed among the isohedra.
- In David Eppstein's paper [*On Polyhedral Realization with Isosceles Triangles*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00116) (link to arXiv abstract), three infinite families of convex monohedra not given above are listed, with isosceles triangle faces: one consisting of a heightened antiprism with pyramids glued to each large opposite face (called a "gyroelongated bipyramid"), a variant of the previous shape in which two halves are rotated about a skew hexagonal cross-section (called a "twisted gyroelongated bipyramid"), and a shape called the "biarc hull" which I can't describe very well but is related to a [sphericon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericon). They cite the paper [*Some New Tilings of the Sphere with Congruent Triangles*](https://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2005/bridges2005-489.html) by Robert Dawson, most of which seem not to translate to monohedral polyhedra but which I haven't checked fully.
- The answers to [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878041/solids-that-are-platonic-apart-from-faces-being-irregular-polyhedra), which provide monohedral polyhedra combinatorially equivalent to the icosahedron but with non-equilateral faces. (The scalene case is not always convex, but can be made so with small distortions to the angles of the triangles involved.) The book *Advances in Discrete and Computational Geometry* mentioned above goes into more detail about the possibility of such polyhedra.

Given the apparent lack of a classification of more restricted classes of polyhedra, I expect that no complete classification exists. However, I'd like to better understand the scope of which examples and impossibility results are known, as I haven't been able to find much in the way of a definitive source tackling this question. I'm hoping this question and its answers can at least serve as a better overview of known convex monohedra than the scattered state of information that seems to exist on the problem at present.

Comment: Interesting question. I am not aware of a classification, but I am also interested in the higher-dimensional analogue of this question. I think it is unclear whether the problem of finding monohedral polytopes becomes easier or harder in $d\ge 4$ (I speak of identical *facets*). In 3D I would probably attempt a first classification by the gonality of the faces: monohedral polyhedra with pentagon faces are probably easiest to classify (are there any others than the regular dodecahedron?). Next up the ones with 4-gonal faces. And triangular faces are probably the hardest.

Comment: @M. Winter: For pentagonal faces, I know of the tetartoid and the pyritohedron, both listed under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Other_pentagonal_dodecahedra. These are combinatorially equivalent to the regular dodecahedron in their incidence structure, but have less symmetry.

Comment: Update: I have cross-posted this question to MathOverflow at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376071/what-are-the-known-convex-polyhedra-with-congruent-faces.

Comment: [This paper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~grunbaum/Nonequifacettablesphere.pdf) of Branko Grunbaum discusses the problem of showing a given polyhedral incidence structure has no monohedral realization, in this case even via nonconvex polyhedra. (The complexity of the given counterexample suggests that perhaps many smaller triangulated surfaces *do* have such realizations, though?)

Comment: Interesting question, do you think it's true that a monohedral polyhedron must be convex and consist of even number of faces?

Comment: @CensiLI If we relax convexity we get additional possibilities - consider taking an icosahedron and "punching in a vertex", ie reflecting a pentagonal pyramid of the polyhedron about its base.